# Proof $\left[ {\hat H,{{\hat p}_i}} \right] = - \frac{\hbar }{i}\frac{{\partial \hat H}}{{\partial {{\hat q}_i}}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

I have a problem with the Hamiltonian, I don't think anything to solve it!!
So could you give me some hints!

- Knowing that: 
  $$\left[ {{{\hat p}_i},{{\hat q}_k}} \right] = \frac{\hbar }{i}{\delta _{ik}}.$$

Hamiltonian is:

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \hat H = \hat q_i^{},\hat q_i^2,\hat q_i^3,....,\hat q_i^n, \\ 
 (n \in N) \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Proof that:
$$\left[ {\hat H,{{\hat p}_i}} \right] =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\frac{{\partial \hat H}}{{\partial {{\hat q}_i}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by induction. I'll drop the operator hats as they're a pain to write.

First step:
Suppose $\hat H = \hat q_k$. Then $[ H, p_i] = [q_k, p_i] = i\hbar \delta_{ik} = -\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}$

So in the special case that the Hamiltonian has this form, the claim is true!

Now suppose that the claim is true for $H = q_i^n$. Then your job is to prove that it's also true for $H = q_i^{n+1}$. Using the **product rule** for commutators, $[\hat A, \hat B \hat C] = [\hat A, \hat B] \hat C + \hat B [\hat A, \hat C]$ should make this straight-forward, but let me know if you need more hints.

Comment: Witt  n = 1=> $\left[ {{q_i},{p_i}} \right] =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\frac{{\partial {q_i}}}{{\partial {q_i}}} =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}$

Assume with n: $\left[ {{q^n}_i,{p_i}} \right] =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\frac{{\partial {q^n}_i}}{{\partial {q_i}}} =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}nq_i^{n - 1}$

Comment: We proof the expression with m =n+1
$\begin{array}{l}
 \left[ {q_i^{n + 1},{p_i}} \right] = \left[ {q_i^n{q_i},{p_i}} \right] = q_i^n\left[ {{q_i},{p_i}} \right] + \left[ {q_i^n,{p_i}} \right]{q_i} \\ 
  = q_i^n\left( { - \frac{\hbar }{i}} \right) + \left( { - \frac{\hbar }{i}} \right)\frac{{\partial {q^n}_i}}{{\partial {q_i}}}{q_i} =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\left( {q_i^n + nq_i^{n - 1}{q_i}} \right) =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\left( {n + 1} \right)q_i^n \\ 
  =  - \frac{\hbar }{i}\frac{{\partial q_i^{n + 1}}}{{\partial {q_i}}}(QED) \\ 
 \end{array}$

Comment: Looks about right :)

Answer (score 0):

From the first commutator relation you can find out how the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ has to look like. Then take the secon relation, don't forget to use the product rule and see which terms cancel each other. In the last term you insert $\hat{p}$ and you're done.

Here I use the position basis for the operators and the wave function, it should work the other way round too.

Following the request for more details:
If you work in position basis, $\Psi=\Psi(q_i)$, you can show that the choice of $p=\frac{\hbar}{i}\partial_{q_i}$ fullfills the first commutator relation.

Then you calculate the second commutator: $[H(q_i),p_i]\Psi(q_i)=Hp\Psi-p(H(q_i)\Psi(q_i)) $ In the second term you have to use the product rule. From now on I drop the dependencies.

$[H,p]\Psi=Hp\Psi-(pH)\Psi-Hp\Psi$

The bracket around $(pH)$ means that $p$ only acts on $H$. Now two terms cancel and your left with $-pH$. Now we insert our knowledge about $p$ and we are done.

The proove using induction is somehow more elegant since it does not use any basis.